# How to get unique values from a collection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I am using C# + VSTS2008 + .Net 3.0. I have an input as a string array. And I need to output the unique strings of the array. Any ideas how to implement this efficiently?

For example, I have input {"abc", "abcd", "abcd"}, the output I want to be is {"abc", "abcd"}.

Comment: The question title is a little misleading. It should probably be "How to get unique collection in C#".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
var uniquevalues = list.Distinct();
```

That gives you an `IEnumerable<string>`.

If you want an array:

```
string[] uniquevalues = list.Distinct().ToArray();
```

---

If you are not using .NET 3.5, it's a little more complicated:

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in list)
{
   if (!newList.Contains(s))
      newList.Add(s);
}

// newList contains the unique values
```

Another solution (maybe a little faster):

```
Dictionary<string,bool> dic = new Dictionary<string,bool>();

foreach (string s in list)
{
   dic[s] = true;
}

List<string> newList = new List<string>(dic.Keys);

// newList contains the unique values
```

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. I am using .Net 3.0, can not use LINQ, any solutions?

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use a `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>(inputStrings);
```

I think I'd also go with linq, but it's also an option.

Edit:
You've update the question to 3.0, maybe this will help: 
[Using HashSet in C# 2.0, compatible with 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687034/using-hashset-in-c-2-0-compatible-with-3-5)

Comment: No problem. It was obvious you'll take Philippe's answer (it's better), but it's always good to have more options.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with Linq its short and sweet but in case u don't wanna LINQ try second Option HashSet

Option 1:

```
string []x = new string[]{"abc", "abcd", "abcd"};    
IEnumerable<string> y = x.Distinct();    
x = Enumerable.ToArray(y);
```

Option 2:

```
HashSet<string> ss = new HashSet<string>(x);
x = Enumerable.ToArray(ss);
```