# Convert a HashSet<T> to an array in .NET

Tags: .net, arrays, hashset

How do I convert a HashSet<T> to an array in .NET?

Comment: `HashSet<T>` is only available in **.Net 3.5**. As such, you can use the `ToArray()` Linq extension method.

Comment: @adrianbanks: Thanks. Anyway, I edited the question to match the answers better.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the [`HashSet<T>.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396374.aspx) method.  This method copies the items from the `HashSet<T>` to an array.

So given a `HashSet<String>` called `stringSet` you would do something like this:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[stringSet.Count];
stringSet.CopyTo(stringArray);
```

Comment: HashSet.ToArray() is simpler

Comment: Is there an ToArray? I can't seem to find it

Comment: @Konstantin HashSet<T> has a .ToArray() method but it is internal. However, you can use LINQ's .ToArray() extension method which internally uses .CopyTo() (because HashSet<T> implements ICollection<T> and LINQ's .ToArray() implementation has a special case for ICollection<T>'s).

Answer (score 31):

If you mean System.Collections.Generic.HashSet, it's kind of hard since that class does not exist prior to framework 3.5.

If you mean you're on 3.5, just use ToArray since HashSet implements IEnumerable, e.g.

```
using System.Linq;
...
HashSet<int> hs = ...
int[] entries = hs.ToArray();
```

If you have your own HashSet class, it's hard to say.

Comment: See the answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687034/using-hashset-in-c-2-0-compatible-with-3-5

Comment: Quote from that answer: "You can use HashSet<T> in a 2.0 application now - just reference System.Core.dll ... Note: This would require you to install the .NET 3.5 framework". IMO, if you use parts of framework 3.5, then you're using 3.5 and not 2.0. Most of the system DLLs are marked as version 2.0.0.0 even on framework 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
function T[] ToArray<T>(ICollection<T> collection)
{
    T[] result = new T[collection.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach(T val in collection)
    {
        result[i++] = val;
    }
}
```

as for any `ICollection<T>` implementation.

Actually in fact as you must reference `System.Core` to use the `HashSet<T>` class you might as well use it :

```
T[] myArray = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(hashSet);
```

Comment: Because it's more generic (it applies to any ICollection<T>) and CopyTo require that you manually allocate the array anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do it even simpler, with `List<T>` constructor (Lists are modern Arrays :).
E. g., in PowerShell:

```
$MyNewArray = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new($MySet)
```