# HashSet equivalent for dotNet 2.0

Tags: c#, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HashSet replacement in C# 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977779/hashset-replacement-in-c-sharp-2-0)

I am in need of a collection that does not allow duplicates. 
In dotNet v4.0 I would use a `HashSet`.

What options do I have in dotNet v2.0?

This is the only alternative I can think of for adding without duplicates:

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
if (!list.Contains(newItem)) list.Add(newItem);
```

But it will be facing much more attemped duplicates than non-duplicates, which makes the `O(n)` nature of `List.Contains` less than appealing.

What other collection should I use instead? Would a `Dictionary<Foo,JunkValue>` be useful?

The collection does not have to be ordered.

Comment: Yes, you would use a dictionary.  It will throw if you try to add a key/value pair where the key already exists.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks my search didn't find that one for some reason.

Comment: @Rotem: it was the first hit when i searched for "hashset 2.0". However, note that you can use a `HashSet<T>` in a 2.0 application. http://stackoverflow.com/a/687042/284240